# Windows server not responding on port 8080

Tags: http, tomcat, tcp, windows-server-2012-r2

I have setup tomcat7 on my new windows server 2012 r2 (default connector port 8080). I am able to run tomcat and access the dashboard by loading http://localhost:8080 in the server's browser.
However, I am losing hair trying to load this page over the web at http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080. The connection simply times out.
When I load http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80 which I read is open by default, it loads the default windows server page full of `welcome` text.
After some reading, I created inbound and outbound rules for opening TCP port 8080, firewall protection is turned off, I still see no change in results even after restarting tomcat server everytime.
When I run `netstat -an` on the server, this line is present:

```
TCP 0.0.0.0:8080    0.0.0.0:0   LISTENING
```

which I presume should mean that the machine is listening to inbound connections on port 8080 from all network interfaces.
Why on earth can't I access my tomcat dashboard over the web?

Comment: [Firewall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209972/how-can-i-open-specific-port-numbers-in-windows-system)?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek that problem is not about failure to browse, it's about fear of leaving firewall turned off. I have done all he did as stated in my question and still failed to access over web

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the inbound rule for TCP 8080 in Windows Firewall, and configure the rule to allow NAT Traversal.